# How to make an activity to appear over current activity

Tags: android

To keep it short, my aim is to pop up an Activity to appear in front of current activity.

Here is an example https://i.stack.imgur.com/WLUOJ.png

It's an widget. When I press a button this activity pops up over other activities.

I want similar activity to popup.

I'm a newbie. So, please be some what in detail.

Comment: you just create Activity and apply Dialog theme. that's it.

Comment: Did u tried inflater concept..?

Comment: declare your activity as dialog Activity.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

So you want the activity to behave like a dialog popup.

This can be achieved by defining the following for an activity in the android manifest file--

```
android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Dialog"
```

Now the activity will behave like a dialog.

Answer (score 1):

Why not use a dialog?

http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/dialogs.html

You can also use an Activity as a dialog, instructions are on the same link.

Answer (score 0):

Use `android:Theme.Holo.Dialog.NoActionBar` as the theme for your activity. Alternatively, you can create your custom theme and use `android:Theme.Holo.Dialog.NoActionBar` as the parent of it.

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve the popup by creating an `Activity` simply declare that activity to theme as a  dialog in your manifest file.

```
   <activity android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Dialog">
```

Check out [Simple Tutorial of Activity as Dialog.](http://techblogon.com/android-activity-dialog/#more-983)

Answer (score 0):

Yea I would try a custom dialogue box. That way, you can customize it to your pleasing. Here's an example:

Activity:

```
LayoutInflater li = LayoutInflater.from(this);
View promptsView = li.inflate(R.layout.your_xml, null);
AlertDialog.Builder alertDialogBuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);

alertDialogBuilder.setView(promptsView); // set your_xml to alert dialog builder

    alertDialogBuilder.setCancelable(false).setPositiveButton("OK",new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog,int id) {
            //action listener for "OK" button

            }
          })
        .setNegativeButton("Cancel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog,int id) {
            dialog.cancel();

            }
          });

    // create alert dialog
    AlertDialog alertDialog = alertDialogBuilder.create();

    // show it
    alertDialog.show();
```

}

your_xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical" >

//Custom layout
</LinearLayout>
```